# Errors while running docker "Error resolving syscall name <>: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall."

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I see following errors while running my docker image on one machine

```
uname -r
3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64

2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name execveat: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name getrandom: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name memfd_create: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name renameat2: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name sched_getattr: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name sched_setattr: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name seccomp: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name breakpoint: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name cacheflush: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
2016/11/01 23:46:56 Error resolving syscall name set_tls: could not resolve name to syscall - ignoring syscall.
```

Do I need to install any missing dependencies to resolve these errors?

```
[nipatel@spgswdev10 xdk]$ docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.10.3
 API version:     1.22
 Package version: docker-common-1.10.3-46.sl7.14.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.6.3
 Git commit:      8f966cb-unsupported
 Built:           Wed Sep 28 09:42:19 2016
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.10.3
 API version:     1.22
 Package version: docker-common-1.10.3-46.sl7.14.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.6.3
 Git commit:      8f966cb-unsupported
 Built:           Wed Sep 28 09:42:19 2016
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
```

Comment: I am seeing this exact same issue.

`CentOs: 7.2.1511  Docker verson: 1.10.3  
    Package version: docker-common-1.10.3-44.el7.centos.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a docker/selinux issue, and advice is to just upgrade libseccomp to libseccomp-2.2.1-1.el7.x86_64 or higher.
I was able to fix with:
`yum upgrade libseccomp`